# How do I add Python to PATH?

Tags: python, linux, path

I have the following

```
ubuntu@ip:/$ whereis python
python: /usr/bin/python3.7 /usr/bin/python3.7m /usr/bin/python3.6m /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.7 /usr/lib/python3.6 /etc/python3.7 /etc/python3.6 /usr/local/lib/python3.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.6 /usr/share/python
ubuntu@ip:/$ python --version

Command 'python' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install python3       
sudo apt install python        
sudo apt install python-minimal

You also have python3 installed, you can run 'python3' instead.
```

How do I set Python so I can just call python in the terminal and so that other programs can use it??

Thanks

Comment: Which one of those pythons do you want to use?

Comment: @martineau I want to use 3.6

Comment: You have to use `export` along with the path to the Python 3.6 directory. See [How to set your $PATH variable in Linux](https://opensource.com/article/17/6/set-path-linux).

Comment: @martineau I did  export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/python3.6 but it still complains that python isnt found...

Comment: If you want the python interpreter in the 3.6 folder to run when you type `python`, then you'll need to create an alias as described in @Muni's answer — otherwise I think you can run it by explicitly typing `python3`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make Python3 as a default python writing into bash alias.

Refer this article: [Configure Python 3 as default on Ubuntu](https://threenine.co.uk/configure-python-3-4-default-ubuntu-14-04/).